# How do I program a new key for 2000 Mercedes-Benz c230 kompressor?

Tags: mercedes-benz, key, fob, c230k

A friend of mine gave me a 2000 Mercedes-Benz c230 compressor. The car has been sitting for three years without running, so it lost programed to the original key.

I called a certified locksmith to come and check it out, and he said that I needed to order a new key fob, so I did. When it came in, it was a newer version of the old key fob, but they say it works just like the old one will.

I called up the locksmith to see if I can get this key fob going, and he said he needs the old key in order to reprogrammed the new one. My friend lost the original key, so now I'm sitting here with the new key fob and no old one.

How can I get this new key programmed?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It was my understanding MB's have to be programmed at the dealership, but I could be wrong.